Downgrading laravel 11 to 10 resulting in error
i want to downgrade my laravel version to 10, but it returns error

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

i was doing the initial downgrade procedure like removing vendor folder, composer.lock. And then i done the
composer install

and when the process of generating optimized autoload files it show the warning

Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Providers\AppServiceProvider" was found in both "C:/laragon/www/CodeCentral-1/app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php" and "C:/laragon/www/CodeCentral-1/vendor/laravel/pint/app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php", the first will be used.

the error before abort the install was

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

how should i resolve this? Does removing App\Providers\AppServiceProvider would work?

Instead of “downgrading”, something that is not commonly supported by any system, can you explain what is wrong with the upgrade?

I dont upgrade from 10 to 11, but it was already 11 that i make the project. I want to downgrade to 10 but it resulted to an error.

If it's a new project, why not create it on version 10 from the start? composer create-project laravel/laravel:^10.0 example-app

Inside of it there was some code that i already wrote. Rather than moving manually from the new v10 project, i'd like to just downgrade it, if it possible.
